# Foreign Key issue SQL

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I cant figure out why this is not compiling It has to do with the foreign key somehow:

```
Drop Table Employee;
Drop Table Department;


Create Table Employee(
EmpNr int not null primary key,
EmpName Varchar(35) not null,
Dept Varchar (2) not null,
Gender char not null
);

Create Table Department(
DeptCode Varchar (2) not null primary key,
DeptName Varchar (35) not null,
Foreign Key (DeptCode) references Employee (Dept)
);

insert into Employee values (001, 'HagarT','DV','M'),
                               (002, 'WongS','DV','F'),
                               (003, 'Jones','MK','F'), 
                               (004, 'MifuneK','SL','M');

insert into Department values ('DV',  'Development'), 
                                 ('MK', 'Marketing'), 
                                 ('RS',  'Research'),                               
                                 ('SL', 'Sales');
```

Comment: Can you include the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You need `Dept` be `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` to work as FK

```
Create Table Employee(
    EmpNr int not null primary key,
    EmpName Varchar(35) not null,
    Dept Varchar (2) unique not null,
    Gender char not null
);
```

As you can see your `Employee` has two rows with `'DV'` so which will be foreign for the `Department`?

I think you want is

```
Create Table Employee(
    EmpNr int not null primary key,
    EmpName Varchar(35) not null,
    Dept Varchar (2) not null,
    Gender char not null,
    Foreign Key (Dept) references Department (DeptCode)
);
```